# Запись массива в текстовый файл

Tags: java, массивы, вывод, запись

У меня на выходе программы двумерный массив 100 х 100 на **Java**, величина значений достаточно большая. Нужно записать этот массив в текстовый файл. Как это сделать наилучшим образом для такого количества элементов? Еще в консоли видно, как значения друг на друга накладываются или просто плотно расположены.

Данные нужны для построения графика в gnuplot.

В консоль вывел таким образом, задав количество символов перед запятой:

```
for (i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%50.2f", Tnew[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
```

Скриншот консоли:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приблизительно таким образом должна выглядеть запись, но для больших данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "на выходе программы"? Массив выводится в консоль? В каком смысле большая величина значений? Покажите часть вывода, чтобы мы поняли, о чем речь, и уточните, в чем все-таки проблема - например, какой вид должны иметь данные в файле и почему не получается привести данные в такой вид. Ни на один вопрос нельзя ответить однозначно, если неизвестно, что нужно получить в результате.

Comment: @therainycat Отредактировал тему.

Comment: Не очень понимаю, какак разница. Выводите данные просто через строчный whitespace, например через пробел, данные ведь не для человека, а для gnuplot, он их сможет прочесть.
http://lowrank.net/gnuplot/datafile-e.html
`In a data file, the data columns are separated by a white-space or tab.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не совсем понятна ваша проблема, но если вы её решили и проблема только в записи в файл, то вместо System.out создайте:

```
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStrem(имя файла));
```

И используйте его вместо System.out так

```
  for (i = 1; i < size - 1; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
          out.printf("%50.2f", Tnew[i][j]);
      }
      out.println();
  }
  out.println();
```

Т.к. System.out это объект класса PrintWriter разница будет только в том, куда будут записаны данные.

Так же я бы добавил пробел в запись  out.printf("%50.2f", Tnew[i][j]); чтобы данные не сливались

```
   out.printf("%50.2f ", Tnew[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вызывайте метод, передавая в аргументы свой массив и строку с абсолютным либо относительным путем и именем файла с его расширением.

```
public static void writeToTxt (int [][] array, String filePathName) throws IOException{
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(filePathName)));
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            writer.write(String.valueOf(array[i][j]));
            writer.write(" ");
        }
        writer.write("\r\n");
    }
    writer.flush();
}
```